# Issues while calibrating my drone with the mavproxy console

Tags: mavlink

Good day everyone,

I am currently building an autonomous drone using mavproxy to (for now) send commands via USB to the flight controller (speedybee f405 v3). I can not arm the drone since it requires RC controller connection (no RC link), would it be possible to disable that flag and still be able to arm the drone. I know it’s not wise to fly without RC but I just want to test the motors without propellers, and RC transmitter is delivered to me in about a month.

Also I have a problem with the magnetic compass calibration running and never ending. I use the command `magcal`. The magnetic compass is incorporated in the GPS GPS M10q-250.

If anyone with experience with drones could help it would be amazing since this would enable me to really start developing the drone.

Thanks for your help !